# how brk pointer grow after calling malloc

Tags: linux-kernel, c, virtual-memory

I'm new to Linux and C, just want to ask how `brk` pointer grow after calling malloc.
We know that the kernel maintains a brk pointer that points to the top of the heap. let's say there is no available free blocks when we call `malloc` to allocate the requested memory and we know `malloc` call `mmap` internally. Below is my questions:

Q1-when `malloc` call `mmap` internally, does `malloc` pass `brk` as the first argument to `mmap` as starting address like:

```
//not 100% correct onlyfor demo purpose
// void *mmap(void *start, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);

void *malloc(size_t size){
  ...
  mmap(brk, size,...);  
  ...                    //line x
}
```

Q2- does other code section(after line x above) inside `malloc` make `brk` grow? or `mmap` internally make the `brk` grow?

Comment: The implementation is much more complicated. You can look at the source code of `malloc`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485675/10622916.

Comment: "we know malloc call mmap internally" - Not always malloc existed before the mmap call existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specifics depend on the `malloc` implementation, but at least in Doug Lea’s implementation (as used by default in the GNU C library), `mmap` and `sbrk` are used independently.

1. When `malloc` calls `mmap`, it uses `mmap` with no base address; effectively, it delegates the allocation to the kernel (after adjusting the requested size to take into account alignment constraints). There’s no expectation that the `mmap`ed memory is contiguous with the existing heap, or that it can be re-used for any other allocation.
2. `mmap` doesn’t touch `brk`. If `malloc` doesn’t end up using `mmap`, it calls `sbrk` directly. [The implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=cd9933b4e580a58a694ebf34e76ac6fecee29c14;hb=HEAD) is described in detail in comments at the top of the file; if you want to follow the `malloc` code, look for the `sysmalloc` function, and bear in mind that `mmap` is `MMAP` and `sbrk` is `MORECORE` in this code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still a little bit confused. 1-if `malloc` call `mmap` without base address, how does the kernel know that it should allocate new virtual memory in the heap area? it might allocate it in other areas which is not the heap 2-what happen if  `malloc` uses `mmap`, then how brk get updated?if `mmap` doesn’t touch brk that means `malloc` will update brk?

Comment: 1. When `malloc` uses `mmap`, it doesn’t want to allocate memory on the heap. 2. When `malloc` uses `mmap`, the program break doesn’t change.

Comment: `malloc` requests heap memory, that is the purpose we use `malloc`, isn't it? if `malloc` uses `mmap` which doesn't allocate memory on the heap, then how do we get heap memory?

Comment: I’ve answered your SO question re. the above.