# Process memory layout - difference between heap, data and mmap areas

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory, mmap, memory-management

I see in the web many conflicting or unclear descriptions of the memory layout of a Linux process. Usually the [common diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64038876/8529284) looks like:

[image]

And a common [description](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-data-segment-is-part-of-the-heap-or-the-heap-is-part-of-it/answer/Sudarshan-43?ch=15&oid=30002660&share=af08bbcb&srid=2KkSm&target_type=answer) would say that:

> The data segment contains only global or static variable which have a
> predefined value and can be modified. Heap contains the dynamically
> allocated data that is stored in a memory section we refer that as
> heap section and this section typically starts where data segments
> ends.

And [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14954147/8529284):

> The heap is, generally speaking, one specific memory region created by
> the C runtime, and managed by `malloc` (which in turn uses the `brk`
> and `sbrk` system calls to grow and shrink).
>
> `mmap` is a way of creating new memory regions, independently of
> `malloc` (and so independently of the heap).  `munmap` is simply its
> inverse, it releases these regions.

Many of the those explanations seem outdated, and I find many discrepancies. For instance, many articles - as the answer above - claim that the heap is used my `malloc`, but this is actualy a library call that's using either `sbrk` or `mmap`, as the `malloc` [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) says:

> Normally, `malloc()` allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts
> the size of the heap as required, using `sbrk(2)`.  When allocating
> blocks of memory larger than **MMAP_THRESHOLD** bytes, the glibc
> `malloc()` implementation allocates the memory as a private
> anonymous mapping using `mmap(2)`.

So if `malloc` in many cases in implemented by `mmap`, what's the difference between the heap and and the mmap area?

Another thing that seems like a contradiction is that many articles (as the `malloc` man page itself) claim that `brk`/`sbrk` adjust the size of the heap, but their [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html) says it actually adjust the size of the **data segment**:

> `brk()` and `sbrk()` change the location of the **program break**,
> which
> defines the end of the process's data segment (i.e., the program
> break is the first location after the end of the uninitialized
> data segment).

So I'm trying to get a clear, up-to-date overall explanation of the memory layout of processes nowadays with the different segments, that also addresses those questions:

1. What is the difference between the heap and the mmap areas? (From some tests I was attempting, by looking at the addresses I got from `mmap` and comparing to the range of the heap in `/proc/self/maps`, it seems that some `mmap` allocated pages are actually allocated inside the heap segment.)
2. Does the **break** signifies the end of the **data segment**, or the end of the **heap**?

Other related questions:

- [how brk pointer grow after calling malloc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/610939/273579)
- [When is the heap used for dynamic memory allocation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/411408/273579)

Comment: This question seems better suited for stack overflow.

Comment: @td211: I disagree.  [SO] is specifically about programming.  While this question is framed in terms of Linux, and has had the [linux-kernel] tag added by a reviewer, it is really more about architecture, concepts and terminology.  It might fit on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com).